# Is it possible to deduce the sum of cosines formula without resorting to the classical geometric proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I've spent this night trying to prove the sum of cosines formula, using only the idea of inner products and no reference to the classic geometrical proof. I did the following:

Using the definition,

$$\langle (a,b),(x,y) \rangle=ax+by$$

now suppose $|(a,b)|=|(x,y)|=1$, this gives me:

$$\langle (a,b),(x,y) \rangle=\cos \theta \cos \phi +\sin \theta \sin \phi \tag{1}$$

I know that this, for $\psi=\theta -\phi$, is:

$$\cos(\psi)=\cos(\theta - \phi)\tag{2}$$

But how can I deduce $(1)=(2)$ without using the classical geometric proof? The proofs in Gelfand/Saul's book are what I mean with classical geometric proof. Is it possible? I've tried to do the following:

Take the projection of the first vector over the second and this gives me one cosine:

$$\cfrac{\langle (\cos \theta,\sin \theta),(\cos \phi,\sin \phi)\rangle }{|(x,y)||(x,y)|}\cdot (\cos \phi ,\sin \phi) $$

$$\langle (\cos \theta,\sin \theta),(\cos \phi,\sin \phi)\rangle \cdot (\cos \phi,\sin \phi)=(\cos \theta \cos \phi + \sin\theta \sin \phi) (\cos\phi ,\sin \phi)$$

$$(\cos \theta \cos \phi + \sin\theta \sin \phi) (\cos\phi ,\sin \phi)=\\(\cos\theta \cos^2 \phi+\sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \phi, \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \phi + \sin\theta \sin^2 \phi )$$

Now, I guess this should be equal to $(1)$, no?

Comment: Do you specifically want a linear algebraic proof?  If so, might as well tag it as such.  If not, it's easy to prove using Euler's theorem $e^{ix} = \cos x+i\sin x$ (I'm unsure if this is what you mean by the classicial geometric proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the (geometric or: coordinate-free) [definition of the inner product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):
$$
\langle (a,b),(x,y) \rangle=|(a,b)|\cdot|(x,y)|\cdot \cos\psi=\cos\psi=\cos(\theta-\phi)
$$
Combine this with your equation $(1)$, to arrive at your desired proof.

Comment: Yes, but thy does it equals $\cos$ in the first place?

Comment: The problem with this is that the $\cos$ doesn't appear there *by definition*. There is a reason for it to be there and I guess the reason is a consequence of the classical geometric proof.

Comment: Actually, the $\cos$ function does appear there by definition. The definition you are using in your post is a consequence of this one, given that we are working inside a euclidean space. Read carefully the first two definitions (algebraic and geometric) given in the link provided in my post. I hope this will clear things up. By the way: the (coordinate-free or geometric) inner product definition, has nothing to do with the geometric proof of the cosine formula for a sum.

Comment: I talked with a professor today. He explained  to me as follows: He said that the $\cos$ in the inner product is a *temporarily different* of the actual geometric cosine, and then one proves that the cosine in the inner product is compatible with the geometric cosine. I guess this is what confused me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also deduce it just from applying 2 rotations to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using matrices.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Represents a counter-clockwise rotation of $\theta$.

So if we wanted to first make a rotation of $\alpha$ and then a rotation of $\beta$ this would create a rotation of $\alpha + \beta$

The corresponding matrix would be

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha + \beta) & -\sin(\alpha + \beta) \\
\sin(\alpha + \beta) & \cos(\alpha + \beta)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\beta) & -\sin(\beta) \\
\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta)
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) \\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) & -(\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)) \\
\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) & \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

An added bonus is that you get the sum formula for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ as well.